# .gif images not copied

Tags: php

I'm having issues with .gif images and processing these. Here is the relevent part of my image processing code. Some of the .gif files are upload while other are not. I cant see any difference between them when it comes to extension. All of them are .gifs according to properties and they play fine in internet explorer on localhost.

```
                        if($fileExt == "jpg" || $fileExt == "jpeg" || $fileExt == "png" || $fileExt == "gif"){
                        $filename = random_filename($alphas).'.'.$fileExt;
                        $destination = 'member/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'/large/'.$filename;
                        move_uploaded_file($file, $destination);
```

Comment: Do some debugging then. Output `$fileExt` for example

Comment: Yes your right. brb with result

Comment: Hmm var_dump gives my gif. strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should echo $filename

```
if($fileExt == "jpg" || $fileExt == "jpeg" || $fileExt == "png" || $fileExt == "gif"){
            $filename = random_filename($alphas).'.'.$fileExt;
            echo $filename . '<br>';
            $destination = 'member/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'/large/'.$filename;
            move_uploaded_file($file, $destination);
}
```

just to confirm that your if block is executing in every occassion. If not echo $fileExt to check that you are getting the expected value for $fileExt

So if it isn't the case, print_r the $_FILES

```
  echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES); echo '</pre>';
```

if you can see error in $_FILES, check your php.ini for upload limit, try to find this line

```
  upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

usually upload fails due to exceeding upload limit, check the file size against upload limit. Adjust if required.

If you still see some problem don't hesitate to ask.